# Can I daisy-chain various connect.js apps together?

Tags: node.js, http

In my application I need to heavily use various middleware using [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect).

Therefore, I have 2 middleware files:

middleware1.js

```
const connect = require('connect');
const app=connect();

app.use(function(req,res,next){
   //do something
   next();
});


module.exports=app;
```

middleware2.js

```
const connect = require('connect');
const app=connect();

app.use(function(req,res,next){
   //do something else
   next();
});


module.exports=app;
```

And my main app (index.js):

```
const connect = require('connect');
const middleware1 = require('./middleware1.js')
const middleware2 = require('./middleware2.js')

const app=connect();

// use middleware1 and middleware 2 here

app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.end('Hello from Connect!\n');
})

app.listen(8090);
```

In my case I want to use both `middleware1.js` and `middleware2.js` into the index.js where the whole app is bootstrapped. How on earth can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is feasible to daisy-chain various connect app together as you can see in this minimal example:

```js
const connect = require('connect');

const app1 = connect();
const app2 = connect();

app2.use(function(req, res){
    res.end('Hello from Connect!\n');
});

app1.use(app2);

app1.listen(8090);
```

Therefore, your index.js should be:

```js
const connect = require('connect');
const middleware1 = require('./middleware1.js')
const middleware2 = require('./middleware2.js')

const app=connect();

app.use(middleware1);
app.use(middleware2);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.end('Hello from Connect!\n');
})

app.listen(8090);
```